# Removing all decimals in PHP

Tags: php, database

get this from my database:

`252.587254564`

Well i wanna remove the `.587254564` and keep the `252`, how can i do that?

What function should i use and can you show me an example?

Greetings

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can do it in PHP:

```
round($val, 0);
```

or in your MYSQL statement:

```
select round(foo_value, 0) value from foo
```

Comment: I don't think this is a correct answer. The asker is not looking to round up. The asker has 252.587254564 and wants to remove the decimals and be left with 252. round($val, 0) would result in 253 (rounding up). The correct answer to the specific question should not round up, it should either remove the decimal or always rounds down.

I would use intval($val)

Comment: this rounds, say you have 315.5, it will round to 316.0. not 316. Incorrect answer

Comment: Well ya, this was answered 10 years ago, when everything was different.. even MySQL's functions output has changed

Answer (score 38):

You can do a simply cast to `int`.

```
$var = 252.587254564;
$var = (int)$var; // 252
```

Answer (score 12):

As Tricker mentioned you can round the value down or you can just cast it to int like so:

```
$variable = 252.587254564; // this is of type double
$variable = (int)$variable; // this will cast the type from double to int causing it to strip the floating point.
```

Answer (score 9):

In PHP you would use:

```
$value = floor($value);
```

`floor`: Returns the next lowest integer value by rounding the value down if necessary.

If you wanted to round up it would be:

```
$value = ceil($value);
```

`ceil`: Returns the next highest integer value by rounding the value up if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

You can just cast it to an `int`:

```
$new = (int)$old;
```

Answer (score 4):

Convert the float number to string, and use intval to convert it to integer will give you 1990

```
intval(("19.90"*100).'')
```

Answer (score 4):

positive number:

```php
round(252.587254564) // 253
floor(252.587254564) // 252
ceil(252.587254564) //252
(int)252.587254564 // 252
intval(252.587254564) // 252
~~252.587254564 // 252
```

negative number:

```php
round(-252.587254564) // -253
floor(-252.587254564) // -253
ceil(-252.587254564) // -252
(int)-252.587254564 // -252
intval(-252.587254564) // -252
~~-252.587254564 // -252
```

if you want just remove decimals without round you can use one of above codes except `round` and `floor`(for negative number).

**But I recommended the last one, it's simpler and faster using prefix `~~`**

Answer (score 3):

Before using above answer what is your exact requirement please see bellow example output.

```
$val = 252.587254564;

echo (int)$val; //252
echo round($val, 0); //253
echo ceil($val); //253


$val = 1234567890123456789.512345;

echo (int)$val; //1234567890123456768
echo round($val, 0);//1.2345678901235E+18
echo ceil($val); //1.2345678901235E+18


$val = 123456789012345678912.512345;

echo (int)$val; //-5670419503621177344
echo round($val, 0);//1.2345678901235E+20
echo ceil($val); //1.2345678901235E+20
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `echo (int) 252.587254564;`

Answer (score 1):

And there is also a not quite advisable method:

```
strtok($value, ".");
```

This cuts of the first part until it encounters a dot. The result will be a string, not a PHP integer. While it doesn't affect using the result much, it's not the best option.

Answer (score 0):

I see many answers, but the question is:

> "Well i wanna remove the .587254564 and keep the 252, how can i do
> that?"

Since the questioner is asking for php, the function in php will be the one for the job.

```
$newValue = floor($value);
```

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL you can use:

```
select floor(field)
```

or in PHP you can use:

```
floor($value);
```