# Remove useless zero after number using php code

Tags: php

we are using this code for displaying shipping charges in magneto site :

```
<?php echo "Selling Price + " . $_excl . " Delivery "; ?>
```

where `$_excl` will return the value.

its displaying results as 10.00, 20.00...etc.

I want to **remove .00** from "10.00" & display only 10.

I checked [here1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903171/removing-all-decimals-in-php) & [here2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531679/remove-useless-zero-digits-from-decimals-in-php)

I tried below codes :

```
echo "Selling Price + " . round($_excl,0) . " Delivery ";
echo "Selling Price + " . round($_excl) . " Delivery ";
echo "Selling Price + " . $_excl + 0 . " Delivery ";
```

nothing worked for me, Please give me updated code for this

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `(int)`, [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) or [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) or [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

```
$num = '10.00';
echo (int)$num ."\n"; //print 10
echo number_format($num,0) ."\n"; //print 10
echo round($num,0) ."\n"; // print 10
echo intval($num) ."\n"; // print 10
```

[`live sample`](http://codepad.org/hqMrdUjz)

So in your case

```
echo "Selling Price + " . (int)$_excl . " Delivery "  .  "\n";
echo "Selling Price + " . number_format($_excl,0) . " Delivery "  .  "\n";
echo "Selling Price + " . round($_excl,0) . " Delivery "  .  "\n";
echo "Selling Price + " . intval($_excl) . " Delivery "  .  "\n";
```

[`live sample`](http://codepad.org/6VvM5Es6)

Comment: can you please update the answer with my code. what change i need to do for this line : `echo "Selling Price + " . $_excl . " Delivery ";`

Comment: its not working for me, seems i am missing somewhere. i will inform you soon.

Comment: this is strange, as you can see in my live sample its working correctly

Comment: its really strange for me too. i am working on the same.

Comment: you can force it with a `str_replace('.00','',$_excl);` but this is not a number manipulation

Comment: Nice:-) finally it worked for me, is it any disadvantage in that ?

Comment: You are just not manipulating number, you are manipulating it as a string

Answer (score 1):

You can use [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
echo "Selling Price + " . number_format($_excl, 0) . " Delivery ";
```

Comment: it displaying like this : `"Selling Price + Delivery"`, but no values are displaying.

Answer (score 1):

`$num + 0` does the trick.

```
echo 125.00 + 0; // 125
echo '125.00' + 0; // 125
echo 966.70 + 0; // 966.7
```

Internally, this is equivalent to casting to float with `(float)$num` or `floatval($num)` but I find it simpler.

> Update

```
echo "Selling Price + " . ($_excl + 0) . " Delivery ";
```

Comment: can you please update the answer with my code. what change i need to do for this line : `echo "Selling Price + " . $_excl . " Delivery` ";

Comment: @Profile101, be sure to put brackets around the addition

Comment: its displaying like this : `Selling Price + 0 Delivery` , only 0 is returning, no correct values.

Comment: @Profile101, add brackets around the addition. See my updated answer.

Comment: Any luck @Profile101?

Comment: i will inform you soon.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
echo "Selling Price + " . (int)$_excl . " Delivery ";
```

eg

```
$f = "10.00";
echo (int)$f; //gives 10
```

hope it hepls :)

Comment: its displaying like this : `Selling Price + 0 Delivery` , only 0 is returning, no correct values.

Comment: Check value of $_excl becuse the example works fine. se edited code

Comment: i checked it, but when i use code in question , its returning 10 as value.