# Delete Decimals on Prices

Tags: php, plugins, decimal

I was wondering if anyone could help me.
Im using a Car rental Plugin but it has every price with decimals.

As we are working with ARS (Argentinian Pesos) we don't need nor use decimals.
Also argentinian prices uses more digits and with double decimal as is showing right now is really hard to understand.

So, as the plugin does not have the function to chance price format i need to tweak the plugin code.

Currently this has an output of $1500.00 but I need to delete/disable/hide the decimals.

Value: 1500
Actual Output: 1500.00
Desire Output: 1500

I will not use decimal at all.

Can anybody please help me?

```
class CRBSPrice
{
    
    
    static function format($value,$currencyIndex)
    {
        $Currency=new CRBSCurrency();
        $currency=$Currency->getCurrency($currencyIndex);
        
        $value=self::numberFormat($value,$currencyIndex);
        
        if($currency['position']=='left') 
            $value=$currency['symbol'].$value;
        else $value.=$currency['symbol'];
        
        return($value);
    }
    


    
    static function formatToSave($value,$empty=false)
    {
        $Validation=new CRBSValidation();
        
        if(($Validation->isEmpty($value)) && ($empty)) return('');
        
        $value=preg_replace('/,/','.',$value);
        $value=number_format($value,2,'.','');
        return($value);
    }
    

    
    static function numberFormat($value,$currencyIndex)
    {
        $Currency=new CRBSCurrency();
        $Validation=new CRBSValidation();
        
        $currency=$Currency->getCurrency($currencyIndex);
        
        if($Validation->isEmpty($value)) $value=0.00;
        
        $value=number_format($value,2,$currency['separator'],$currency['separator2']);
        return($value);
    }
    
    
    static function calculateGross($value,$taxRateId=0,$taxValue=0)
    {
        if($taxRateId!=0)
        {
            $TaxRate=new CRBSTaxRate();
            $dictionary=$TaxRate->getDictionary();
            
            if(array_key_exists($taxRateId,$dictionary))
                $taxValue=(float)$dictionary[$taxRateId]['meta']['tax_rate_value'];
        }
        
        if(!is_numeric($value)) $value=0.00;
        if(!is_numeric($taxValue)) $taxValue=0.00;
        
        $value*=(1+($taxValue/100));
        
        return($value);
    }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  And at what point in your attempt are you encountering a problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing all decimals in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903171/removing-all-decimals-in-php)

Comment: Your actual output has 2 decimals since your call to number_format() says so.

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't expose an important point: I do not know how to write php. I only barely can read it. So I need to know what to change in that code so the number format is without decimals.